# How to upload a file with PUT in HTTPie

Tags: http, upload, put, httpie

I'm searching for the syntax to write a `PUT` operation that upload a file with HTTPie. Please could you point me to the right syntax ? I could not find a way to do so on the official documentation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To achieve this with httpie, you need to do two things:

1. [Set the HTTP method](https://httpie.org/doc#http-method) to `PUT`, which is trivial: `$ http PUT […]`
2. Pass the contents of the file, for which there are various ways:

[Redirected input](https://httpie.org/doc#redirected-input):

```
$ http PUT httpbin.org/put Content-Type:image/png < /images/photo.png
```

[Request data from a filename](https://httpie.org/doc#request-data-from-a-filename) (automatically sets the `Content-Type` header):

```
$ http PUT httpbin.org/put @/images/photo.png
```

[Form file upload](https://httpie.org/doc#file-upload-forms):

```
$ http --form PUT httpbin.org/put photo=@/images/photo.png
```