# Switching from CURL to HTTPie. Equivalent of CURL -T

Tags: curl, httpie, xbase, clipper

I am working with [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) which is integrated into an [xBase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBase) program.

And the *curl* command line by me includes the option *-T* to download a local file to a [CalDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) calendar. I tried to find it in HTTPie, but I did not find an equivalent command. Does HTTPie have such an option as -T in cURL?

Answer (score 0):

From cURL's manual:

```
       -T, --upload-file <file>
              This transfers the specified local file to the remote URL.
```

It seems you are looking for the upload functionality. In HTTPie, depending on what the host server is expecting, you have multiple ways to upload a file:

A) [Redirected input](https://httpie.org/doc#http-method):

```
$ http PUT httpbin.org/put Content-Type:image/png < /images/photo.png
```

B) [Request data from a filename](https://httpie.org/doc#redirected-input) (automatically sets the `Content-Type` header):

```
$ http PUT httpbin.org/put @/images/photo.png
```

C) [Form file upload](https://httpie.org/doc#request-data-from-a-filename):

```
$ http --form PUT httpbin.org/put photo=@/images/photo.png
```

Original answer by [Jakub Roztocil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834297/15330941).